# Error when plotting dates and ozone data

Tags: r, date, plot

I am trying to add dates to a time series plot. I would like to get the date into a format where it is read and plotted as the date. However, I am getting the error: Error

> in 60 * offset : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

I am not sure what to try next to solve this error with my dates to get it to plot.

The type is list for variable D and double for variable extractdate.

I have included sample data below. I am only looking at the date and O3 columns for this plot. In R, the date data was read in as %Y-%m-%d %H.

Here is the portion of my code that is giving the issue:

```
extractdate <- c(CurrentOzoneVC$date)
  D <- as.data.frame((c(CurrentOzoneVC$date)), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")
  dates = as.chron(D[,1], "%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

here is some sample data:

> ABBR   DATE    O3  SWS VWS
>
> HAVO-VC    10/01/1986 00   -999    -999    -999
>
> HAVO-VC    10/01/1986 01   -999    -999    -999
>
> HAVO-VC    10/01/1986 02   -999    -999    -999

Here is how it is read in R but with 351 dates:

1986-09-30 20:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. You should'nt be specifying the date format in that last line of code. That was the non-numeric argument mentioned in the error message.

This works, for instance:

```
require(chron)
require(lubridate)

extractdate <- mdy_h("10/01/1986 00")
extractdate

D <- as.data.frame(extractdate, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")
dates = as.chron(D[,1])
dates
```

Whereas if you run it with that format string:

```
require(chron)
require(lubridate)

extractdate <- mdy_h("10/01/1986 00")
extractdate

D <- as.data.frame(extractdate, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H")
dates = as.chron(D[,1], "%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

> Error in 60 * offset : non-numeric argument to binary operator